Docker, PyQt5, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
I want to dockerize this app:
# app.py

import sys

# 1. Import QApplication and all the required widgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget

# 2. Create an instance of QApplication
app = QApplication([])

# 3. Create your application's GUI
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("PyQt App")
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 280, 80)
helloMsg = QLabel("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>", parent=window)
helloMsg.move(60, 15)

# 4. Show your application's GUI
window.show()

# 5. Run your application's event loop
sys.exit(app.exec())

the dockerfile is:
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Update package repository and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Run the PyQt5 app when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

after build with docker build -t myapp . and start with docker run --rm -it myapp:
docker run --rm -it myapp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

EDIT:
I'm using apt-get instead of pip because I get an error with pip and the suggested solution is to use apt-get: importerror: libgl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory (PyQt5)
Using RUN pip install --no-cache-dir PyQt5 leads to this error:
docker run --rm -it myapp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


You need to install PyQt5 from pip I think, so add in RUN something like this: RUN pip install --no-cache-dir PyQt5 alongside other installation commands.

pip is the usual method of installing python packages.  Why are you using apt-get ?

(Once you get past this, actually running GUI applications in Docker is itself tricky and not especially portable to non-Linux hosts.  A non-Docker virtual environment might be easier here.)

Create a requirements.txt file with a list of the required packages.
PyQt5==5.15.10

Update the Dockerfile.
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libgl1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

The Dockerfile uses

pip to install the Python package and
apt-get to install the shared library (libGL.so.1) required by the Python package.

The above Dockefile solves the problem in the original question. However the application still doesn't run due to other dependency issues.
But, once the dependency issues are resolved there's another problem: launching a Qt application requires a display. A Docker container is a headless environment. So to get this to run you can install xvfb, which creates a virtual framebuffer in the container.
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        xvfb \
        libgl1 \
        libxcb-xinerama0 \
        libxkbcommon-x11-0 \
        libxcb1 \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libxcb-icccm4 \
        libxcb-image0 \
        libxcb-keysyms1 \
        libxcb-render-util0 \
        libxcb-shape0 \
        libdbus-1-3 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /app

ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
ENV QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
ENV QT_DEBUG_COMPONENT=1

ENV DISPLAY=:99

CMD Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset & \
    python app.py


now I get antother error:
`docker run --rm -it myapp
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.`

Have updated the answer with other missing dependencies and fixed missing DISPLAY in container.

now there is no error, bur after docker run -t myapp the gui doesn't appear.

Correct. The application is running inside the Docker container and the GUI is being rendered onto the frame buffer. The Docker container is a headless environment. You need the frame buffer to imitate having a display attached to the container. This is a separate issue though and I believe that the problems from the original question have been addressed.
